Axios keeps on refetching when api returns http.status 204 and browser freezes
I have written an api endpoint which returns 204 when there are no values in the table.
I am using tanstack query like this

  const api = "http://localhost:3000/api/test?query=id,name,age";
  const { isLoading, data, isIdle } = useQueryHook(api, "students");
  console.log(data);

   if (isLoading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }

  if (isIdle) {
    return <div>No data loaded yet</div>;
  }


The api returns this
  object{
    status: 204,
    statusText: "No Content"
  }

The problem is when the api returns 204, react-query keeps refetching the api until the browser freezes. Can someone help how to handle this
I have also tried the below
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false, // default: true
    },
  },
});

useQueryHook looks like this
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import axios from "axios";

export const useQueryHook = (api: string, queryKey: string)=>{
    return useQuery(queryKey, async() => {
        const response = await axios.get(api);
        
        return response
    });
}



API Response is below

Networks tab

origin header from the api
    e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
        AllowOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:5173", "https://test.net"},
        AllowHeaders: []string{echo.HeaderOrigin, echo.HeaderContentType, echo.HeaderAccept},
    }))


Can you show the code of useQueryHook ? It doesn't look like the usual useQuery

@Xapadoan - I have updated this post adding useQueryHook

I couldn't reproduce your issue. Can you show what happens in your network tab on the browser ?

In the networks tab, I get CAUTION: request is not finished yet and the browser keeps spinning. As I mentioned, this only happens if the api returns a status of 204 i.e No Content. If the api returns data then there are no issues

Can you show the piece of code of the response on the api ? I suspect the server doesn't actually respond

added the api response screenshot

console.log shows the data (i'ts the one right in your component right ?).
So i guess this request succeeds.
However, the network tabs show a status of 304.
When trying to send a 304 response with no origin header, axios / useQuery refetches (as if error)

of-course, I am sending the origin header. Updated the code with the origin header

something to do with tanstack table I suppose. The tanstack table keeps re-fetching when there are no rows. Also let me refactor the code by implementing useEffect hook
